# How to unmount ext partition in Kubuntu 10.04?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ntfs, kubuntu, ext

I want to install Windows 7 again on my notebook over kubuntu 10.04 that I used for few months. Issue is that ext partion where is Kubuntu is locked somehow and can't format it/ delete it with Windows install.Any ideas how to trick this?

Comment: Do you mean Kubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd boot using (K)/Ubuntu Live CD, and use the partition manager or gparted to remove the partitions.

Comment: I end up doing same thing, just deleted the partition with gparted in live cd and use the free space to make new ntfs one.Typing from win 7 :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or use Live CD and dd command to zero out the first few blocks.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda (or whatever disk your netbook primary is) count=20
```

Afterwards, Windows will see an "uninitialized disk" and will let you proceed with install.  This assumes you're not wanting to keep anything from the netbook HD.